# Grails queries with criteria: how to get back a map with column?

Tags: hibernate, grails, createcriteria

Is it possible, to query grails with criteria and receive a list of maps instead of a list of lists? I would like to have the column names in the results in order to then work with an 'associative array' rather then numeric array offsets. I currently do something like

```
    def topFiveUsers = BlogEntry.createCriteria().list {
        projections {
            count('id')
            groupProperty('author')
        }
        maxResults 5
    }
```

Which results in `[[123, app.User:1][111, app.User:2][...]...]`, i.e. a list of lists. I would rather want something like `[[posts:123, author: app.User:1][posts: 111, author app.User:2][...]...]`.

As always: help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 31):

Use [resultTransformer()](https://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/5.0.x/api/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.html).
As the parameter use [CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/CriteriaSpecification.html#ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
The documentation and examples on this topic is scarce. But here's an example:

```
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification

BlogEntry.withCriteria {
  maxResults 5
  resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
  projections {
    count('id', 'total')
    groupProperty('author', 'author')
  }      
}
```

Note that alias is required for all projections. Otherwise, the resulting map consists of nulls.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :(
`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.resultTransformer() is applicable for argument types: (org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer) values: [org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer@7a78d380]`

Answer (score 2):

```
def topFiveList = []
topFiveUsers.each { rec ->
    topFiveList << [posts: rec[0], author: rec[1]]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def converted = topFiveUsers.collect{ [posts: it[0], author: it[1]] }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Of course I can transform the result later on - that is what I am doing at the moment. Then again I want to skip the overhead of postprocessing the result set. I guess that somewhere in the hibernate code the very same transformation happens anyway...

Comment: Shortly after I posted, it occurred to me that you weren't interested in a two-step solution.

Comment: No worries! Thank you anyway for your support! se is just great!